# MySQL bindings for Rails 2.3.5 on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, macports, rubygems

I have a rails environment which I set-up with macports. I recently updated macports which seems to have had the side effect of breaking rails. When I try to boot a rails server I get:

`$ ./script/server 
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/mysql.bundle: dlopen(/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/mysql.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient.15.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/mysql.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9/mysql.bundle`

I've tried reinstalling the mysql gem many times using various configurations I've found around the web but nothing seems to help. Also, when I try to use rake I get:

`rake db:migrate
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.1 (you have 1.0.1). Please`gem update --system`and try again.`

Even though:

`gem --version
1.3.6`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was that I had rails installed under macports, and also as a gem. I uninstalled all the rails components from macports and just stuck with the gems version and it seems to have made the MySQL problem go away.